# PC can be 1 server DNS but not the other

Tags: networking, dns, remote-desktop

So we have a Windows 7 Embedded Thin Client out on our production floor.  It has been out there for a few years and never had any issues with it.  We have an ERP server that the users access the Terminal Server to use.  When a user logs into the computer it runs a login script that creates an RDP to the server on the desktop.

The Terminal Server has 2 DNS names (company-ts and ERPname for examples).  The computer will connect to the company-ts name successfully but it cannot find the ERPname DNS on the network.  I tried an nslookup and got the the computer cannot find the DNS name.  All other computers on the network find the DNS name fine.

I tried the standard flushdns, winsock reset, turned off IPv6 on both the client and server, DHCP and manual IP, no duplicate IP's, and still does not wan tot connect to 1 of the 2 DNS names.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If you compare the list of DNS servers currently being used by the system with the problem, which can be checked with `ipconfig /all` or `netsh interface ipv4 show dns`, against those that do not, are they the same or different?

Comment: They are the same.  Primary DNS is 192.168.0.7 and secondary is 192.168.0.3.  The server in question is 192.168.0.12

Comment: You could use [DNS Query Sniffer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dns_query_sniffer.html) from NirSoft, which is free, to observe DNS queries and responses, which might provide you with a clue to track down the cause of the problem. [I've found it helpful in DNS troubleshooting](http://support.moonpoint.com/reviews/software/windows/network/dns/DNSQuerySniffer/), since I can see DNS queries issued by systems and a server's response or determine if the client system is even issuing a query rather than using a cached value.